# Re Install android OS in Mobile Phone

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rom-flashing, rom

I am using **LG optimus E 400**.

Recently, I have rooted my Android phone. After rooting, it's not booting up now; just displaying white screen.

I have tried go to the boot loader by pressing (Hold POWER + Vol Down) but it's not working in my phone.

After some searching in Google, I found that the solution is re-installing the Android OS. How do I do that? Is any other recovery option?

Thanks.

Comment: Re-Installing means to flash the ROM/firmware again. I just added the appropriate tags to your question; follow them (start with the tag wikis) for more information. One question you surely want to see is [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for suggestion.I have downloaded Firmware, then how can I install it on my phone.?

Comment: That's usually described at the place where you've downloaded it. Methods differ, as do the formats the firmware comes shipped. Not knowing what phone you have, and what ROM/Firmware you've downloaded, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I am not able to connect my phone to PC. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Could you please update your question with some more details: What firmware you downloaded (and where, a link to that page would help as well), what the description says you should do to update, where exactly you are hung, if there are any error messages and, if so, which? As said, unless you add those details there's nothing I can do to help you more.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: V10A_03.kdz is the firm ware

Comment: Now the problem is I am not able to connect my phone to PC and I didn't know how to Install firmware without connecting phone to PC.

Comment: Still missing details, see above: Install instructions? Source of that `.kdz` file? Etc. Also, I never flashed `.kdz` files -- so maybe another LG user who already has experience with that might drop in. Please also explain why you are not able to connect your phone to your PC -- what's the problem? Missing a cable?

Comment: @Izzy I resolved it using this tool http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2020737. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: You're welcome, Vijesh! If you wouldn't mind: Maybe you could sum up the steps you have performed, and make it an answer? That would help others when running into the same trouble. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Solution as per link provided by OP:</sup>

Vijesh finally was able to solve his issue using the [All-In-One Toolkit](http://www.playallatonce.com/toolkit/), following the instructions from [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2020737). This toolkit requires Windows. Not explicitly mentioned in the XDA thread, but most likely this means you've also to install the appropriate device drivers for your smartphone. But it looks like the toolkit offers to do that for you as well, see the item *I - Install APX drivers* in below screenshot:

[image: AIO Toolkit (click to enlarge)]
<sup>The All-In-One Toolkit (Source: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2020737); click image for larger variant)</sup>

The tool seems to be pretty self-explaining. For the installation, you simply run the self-extractor, which prompts you for a target directory. Then you start the tool, and select the wanted item (here probably *6 - LG Update Tool*). Again, everything runs almost automatically -- simply follow the instructions given. The `.kdz` file should be flashed then to the device, and you'll end up with the fresh ROM installed.